# Ffmpeg decompress xz/gz/zip in memory

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, xz

I have a xz compressed y4m raw video file (`sintel-4k.y4m.xz`) and I would like to transcode it using ffmpeg, decompressing in memory. I do not have enough disk space to decompress the file to disc and then transcode. Is there any way to achieve this, linux (WSL2) or windows (preferably)?

Comment: Do you have a xz decompressor in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have installed `xz`:

```
xzcat sintel-4k.y4m.xz | ffmpeg -i pipe: ...
```

However, depending on where the moov metadata is located in your stream, you may encounter a pipe error. See the accepted answer to
[this question](https://superuser.com/questions/479063/ffmpeg-pipe-input-error) for an explanation.

Note: `xzcat` is an alias for `xz --decompress --stdout`

Comment: y4m files don't have a moov box. The header in y4m is always at the front.

Comment: Thank @Gyan, I'm not familiar with the y4m format. I'll leave the caveat in place in case anyone else is applying this solution to other formats that do have moov.